# Regex for matching a word without a ( after it

Tags: regex, d, regex-lookarounds, parentheses

What regex would check a line for a word that is not followed by a `(` character? I tried `(\w+)(\?!\()` but it doesn't work, and `(\w+)[^\(]` matches anything by treating the last letter as the `[^\(]` part. I am using the D programming language.

Examples of things that should match:

It should match the `asdf` in the following:

```
asdf blah 
asdf.beef
(asdf)
```

but not in these:

```
asdf(blah)
```

However, in `asdf(blah)`, the `blah` would be matched. Also in `asdf blah` and `asdf.beef`, the `blah` and `beef` would also be matched.

Comment: What about `blah` and `beef`? Should they be excluded?

Comment: @BeemerGuy, sorry, faulty examples. Let me fix it.

Comment: what language?  Are you looking for a perl regex?

Comment: @russ: "I am using the D programming language.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about D's capabilities.  If it supports the perl regexp language, you can do this:

```
 \w+\b(?!\()
```

The (?!xxx) construct is used for a zero-width negative lookahead.  You need the \b word boundary to keep it from matching all but the last letter of a word that's followed by a paren.

EDIT: I have tweaked M42's good idea below so that it works in D.  Try this

```
 (\w+)\b([^\(]|$)
```

The first capture group should contain the words you're interested in.

Comment: This isn't working either. Unmodified, I get a runtime error: `*+? not allowed in atom`. So I escaped the `?` with a ` \ `. But even so, doesn't work.

Comment: @John Zane -- hmm, I'm not sure.  According to http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_regexp.html The D programming language supports ECMA (aka javascript) regular expressions.  When I tried that expression in javascript it worked.

Comment: @John Zane -- just downloaded the D compiler, wrote a quick program to test it and got the same error as you.  They may not support the full regular expression syntax.  Negative lookahead is a tough feature to implement and they may have left it out.

Comment: @John Zane OK I think we have it now, check out the last edit.

Comment: @russ, brilliant, I can't believe you downloaded the D compiler just to test it out. And by the way, it works beautifully. Thanks, answered, and +1'd.

Comment: Here's a simpler version: `\w+(?![\w(])`.  With the `\w` in the negative lookahead, there's no need for the `\b`.  And, since the lookahead doesn't consume any characters, there's no need for the `|$` ("or end of string") alternative.

Comment: @Alan Moore: good points.  Unfortunately the D programming language doesn't support negative lookahead.

Comment: Hmmm. They claim D's regexes are compliant with ECMA-262, same as JavaScript, VBScript and ActionScript. And yet, they have no lookaheads or non-capturing groups; a pretty major deviation if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
/^\(?(\w+)\b(?:[^\(]|$)/
```

**Not** tested with D compiler, but it works in Perl.

According to russ comment, the `(?:)` construct is unknown in D :

```
/^\(?(\w+)\b([^\(]|$)/
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track here.  The D compiler doesn't support the (?: construct, and we don't want to match the ^ and leading paren as in your expression.  I think what you were going for is this: (\w+)\b([^\\(]|$)

Comment: @russ: OK for the `(?:)` but the paren at the begining is needed  because that will match `blah` in the last example : `asdf(blah)`

Comment: ^\\(?(\w+)\b([^\\(]|$) will not match that blah in asdf(blah), because of the ^ at the beginning.  (\w+)\b([^\\(]|$) will match the blah.  Just because blah is preceded by a ( doesn't mean you have to have it in your regex.  This is the difference between trying to create a regex that matches an entire string and creating a regex that matches a portion of the string, which is what he needs.

Answer (score -1):

```
(\w+)[^\(\w]
```

so you are negating both the ( and the \w?

Comment: This regex won't work if the match is at the end of the string. It also fails to reject words followed by a `(`, so it's completely wrong.